# Customizing build.xml in Android r20

Tags: android

I used to use my customized build script to build apk in Android in the previous versions. After I updated to Android Development tools r20, I can no longer use my own build script. I have been trying to fix it until I obtain a nullpointerexception in the part that checking library dependency.

Do anyone how to fix it? I am using the build.xml in tools/ants/ and trying to include the sheklock action bar library.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you already solved it, but you can avoid all those issues by updating your Eclipse to Juno (4.2). I had the same problem then I waited for a stable version of eclipse now it is working fine, hope this helps